# How to update/write to a text file stored in blobstore 2

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I need to do 10,000 times datastore read and 3000 times of datastore write everyday, which costs me some money.

My current solution is just to upload a text file to GAE and read the text file in every request.

My text file is

```
productid--- price--- description---xxx----xxxx-xxxx
```

However, my need is that I also want to write/edit/update text file. Is it possible?

Is these any advice for me? I dont want to use datastore.

Comment: Define "a lot" and "some". Are you using memcache already? How does you data look? Would it be a better fit for Cloud SQL?

Comment: i modify my question to make it more clear. I havent try memcache and Cloud SQL, will try it. thanx

Comment: Once finalized blobs can not be written to any more. Why don't you want to use datastore? It's a perfect fit for structured and mutable data.

Comment: Datastore read and write cost money ):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use Blobstore to store your files then you won't be able to modify them since blobs are [immutable](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Introducing_the_Blobstore) on Google App Engine:

> Blobs can't be modified after they're created, though they can be deleted.

You should use datastore instead and more specific the [`ndb.TextProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#types) to store your text files since there is no length limit and you can easily create/update/delete. Since it's necessary to do all these requests per day there is nothing you can do about the fact that you will have to pay for it. Just make sure that you are following the best practices and also take a look on the [Appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) so you'll be able to monitor your read/writes.

Comment: Isn't there a maximum entity size for `ndb`?  I store some text files in blobs because they are bigger than the max entity size for `db`.

Comment: thanx. I tried ndb.TextProperty before and i really cost a lot of data read operation.

Comment: @John there is no limit in the `ndb.TextProperty` (check the description from the link) and in the backend I think they are storing them as blobs.. it's just hidden for you.. in the long run you will be better of using the TextProperty instead of handling yourself the blobs through the Files API...

Comment: @Kekito I didn't notice that you made the comment regarding the limits.. no they don't have any.

Comment: @Lipis, thanks for the info.  I've been waiting to switch to ndb and that is another good reason to.

Comment: @Kekito there are no bad reasons to switch to ndb.. and in case you are not aware of it.. you can even use both.. since in the backend the datastore is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the files API to create blobs.  As already noted, you can't edit a blob, but you can do essentially the same thing by creating a new blob with the files API, copying/editing the data from the original blob to the new blob, and then replacing the old blob with the new one.

It works, but it is not ideal.  The files API seems to cause a fair number of exceptions so you need to make sure to have good error checking in that part of your code.